# Оценка пи методом Монте-Карло в R (RStudio)

Tags: r, rstudio

Оценка π: Представьте единичный круг, вписанный в единичный квадрат. Cчитайте, что вписанный круг является мишенью для игры в дартс. Если бы вы случайно выбрали дротики, мы могли бы подумать, что любой брошенный дротик мог бы поразить любую точку единичного квадрата с равной вероятностью (мы не будем рассматривать возможность вообще не ударять по квадрату).

Таким образом, через базовую геометрию:
P (попадание в единицу окружности) = (# дротиков внутри единичного круга) / (# дартс внутри квадрата) = (πr^2)/(4r^2) = π/4 где r = 1/2 ( в нашем случае) - радиус окружности.

Используйте это соотношение для оценки π через моделирование методом Монте-Карло.
Случайным образом cгенерируйте (x, y) координатную пару, определите, попадает ли она в круг или просто в квадрат (Hint: π определяет единичный круг), а затем вычислите π, используя соотношение выше.
Делая это тысячи раз, вы получите приближение π.
Рассмотрите эффективность при написании кода для этого моделирования.

Мой код выглядит примерно так, но как получить окружность, о которой говорится выше?

```r
set.seed(192)
m=1000; n=1000
mat=replicate(m,runif(n)) # create matrix of uniform random numbers
dframe=data.frame(mat)    # transform into data frame
for (i in 1:m){
  for (j in 1:n) {
    dframe[i,j]=dframe[i,j] + cos(pi/2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://helloacm.com/r-programming-tutorial-how-to-compute-pi-using-monte-carlo-in-r/) описан весь процесс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще использовать циклы в языке R признак дурного тона...

```
N<-100000000
x<-runif(N,0,1)
y<-runif(N,0,1)
z<-sqrt(x*x+y*y) 
length(which(z <1))/N*4
```